# Ubuntu 1804 libqt5webkit5 does not support JS promise

Tags: qt

Ubuntu 1804 libqt5webkit5 does not support JS promise. We found this issue during integrating Saml auth with Azure and since libqutwebkit5 on Ubuntu 1804 does not support JS promise, SAML auth always failed.

Here is some discussion with qt5webkit5 on GitHub:
https://github.com/qtwebkit/qtwebkit/issues/918

When will Ubuntu upgrade the libqt5webkt5 to support this `promise` feature?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: Then is there any plan to upgrade this qt5webkit5 lib in the furture? I saw from 16.04 to 18.04 it has been upgraded. But looks like there is no update from 18.04 to 20.04.